# Difference between: (object) o == null and (((object) o) == null

Tags: c#, casting

I tried to check arguments for null, and I found a question in my mind:
What's the difference between:

```
if ( (object) o == null ) ...
```

and

```
if ( ((object) o) == null ) ...
```

Edit: variable o can be of Any reference type (with overloaded == operator on not).

Comment: No difference, casting comes before comparison

Comment: This is only a stylistic difference, the code is equivalent. Casting has higher operator precedence compared to `==`. Explicit parentheses are easier to understand for those who didn't memorize the precedence table.

Comment: Well, example 2 doesn't compile because it has unbalanced `()`s.

Comment: There is none. It's the same. The extra parens in the second example are superfluous. Cast operator has greater precedence than `==` operator. EDIT: lol. I didnt notice that missing parenthesis :)

Comment: if ((object) o) == null) ..this wont complie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  if ((object) o) == null) ...
```

is a mistake. Maybe you want to write

```
  if (((object) o) == null) ...
```

So you cast `o` to `Object` then you test if it equals `null`

It is the same thing except that in `if (((object) o) == null) ...` you made it explicitly (human friendly) with the `()`

All these notations accomplish a same test.

Comment: So there is no any difference in generated IL?

Comment: no difference! It is the same as writing `if(o==null)`

Comment: if (o==null) with use operator == on object o if it has overloaded that operator

Comment: ah okay you are write @zgnilec I have edited my answer

Answer (score -2):

Both are same.

in first case - comparison is made before casting. First it will compare with null then cast to Object.

in second case - casting is made before comparison. First it will cast o to Object then compare it with null.

Comment: How come? casting always comes before comparison.

Comment: i didn't get your question..

Comment: I mean casting has higher operator precedence compared to `==` operator. in all cases, casting is made before comparison even if there is no `()`s.

Comment: yeah you are right but in case of method call and casting, casting has lower precedence than method call.

Comment: Sure? I don't thing so! @Arjit, I suggest you try it first (for you to be sure).

Comment: I don't remember operator precedence. but before trying to answer such question, I would check MSDN to see if my guess is right, or at least, test it with code (if you don't have VS installed, there is always [IDEOne](http://ideone.com)